# Wildcard on usernames in search scopes

Tags: search-scope

I want to exclude multiple system users from the search scope something like

Rule                                  behavior
AccountName = TEST\Systemuser-1       Exclude
AccountName = TEST\Systemuser-2       Exclude
AccountName = TEST\Systemuser-3       Exclude

I want to replace it with something general like
AccountName = TEST\Systemuser-*       Exclude

is this possible (not working like this)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MOSS 2007, you can use prefix matches to have a sort of wildcard.  So you would only need to put AccountName=TEST\Systemuser- to crawl through all of them.

I use SharePOint 2010

Just did the research, ans it seems that sharepoint 2010 allows you to use prefix matching when querying.  Here is the link I found http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh148698%28v=office.14%29.aspx

I found this link from the Manage Search Scopes page through Microsoft, so I assume that prefix matching would work when using a Search Scope.

Comment: It might work for higher versions though, the only reference I can find for it dates back to 2009, so I just assumed so.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to exclude those system users from your profile import.  The easiest method is move all system accounts to an OU exclude.  If you cannot do that you can define a filter rule that exclude accounts based on naming convention or attribute.  If you do not have a naming convention in place for system accounts I recommend you use one of the AD extended attributes and update that with an identifier shared with all accounts -then filter on that.